# How to fix cannot GET on page hard refresh using CTRL+shift+R in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, express, routes, react-router, page-refresh

I am facing a small issue on page `hard refresh` using `CTRL+shift+R` . It is returning with an error of `Cannot GET /blogs`.

I have seen some solution where it is suggested to make a change in `server.js` and still I am getting the same issue with hard refresh.

any solution to fix it?
what do I need to change here to make it work?

//server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));

// Serve static assets if in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // SET static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

//routing links

```
<Navigation >
    <Link to="/#">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/about">About Me</Link>
    <Link to="/projects">Projects</Link>
    <Link to="/resume">Resume</Link>
    <Link to="/blogs">Blogs</Link>
    <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
    
    
    <MenuLogin/>
</Navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution by using `hashrouter`

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render((
  <HashRouter>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>
), holder)
```

As [Defined here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.1.1/FAQ.md#why-doesnt-my-application-render-after-refreshing)